# Connecting SQL Server 2012 database to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I am trying to connect my project in visual studio to my database using SQL Server 2012. this is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CollegeManagementSystem.lib
{
public class DatabaseConnection
{
    public static SqlConnection Con;

    public static SqlConnection GlobalConnection()
    {
        string ConString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-JTVC4I1\\SQLEXPRESS;" + Global.ServerName + ";Initial Catalog=College" + Global.Database + ";Integrated Security=True;User Id=sa" + Global.SUserId + ";Password=123" + Global.SPassword + ";Connection Timeout=1000";
        Con = new SqlConnection();
        Con.ConnectionString = ConString;
        if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
        Con.Open();
        return Con;
    }
```

the name of my database is college.db, i am also confused i have a database in the server called master.db that has the same table i have created in my database college.db but i did not create it.

and I get the error :

> A Network-related or instance-specific error occurred when
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I am running my SQL Server Locally. How can i fix this?

Comment: what is the value of `Global.ServerName` ?

Comment: public static string ServerName = "DESKTOP-JTVC4I1\\SQLEXPRESS";

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see what the value of ConnString is. I suspect you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string's `Integrated Security=True`. This means the `User Id` and `Password` attributes you specified will be ignored and the current Logged Windows Identity will be used.

Try changing your connection string to  `Integrated Security=False`

More details can be found at [MSDN SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
>   Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.
>   If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string like below. Because `Global.ServerName` already have the server name but in your code this get duplicated. Also I think `Global.Database`, `Global.SUserId`, `Global.SPassword` are duplicated.

```
string ConString = @"Data Source=" + Global.ServerName + 
        ";Initial Catalog=" + Global.Database + 
        ";Integrated Security=False;User Id=" + Global.SUserId + 
        ";Password=" + Global.SPassword + ";Connection Timeout=1000";
```

Comment: the database worked. but when i try to login it prompt that the username and password is incorrect, both username and password are called admin.

Comment: did you tried my updated answer? what is the actual username password? and what is the value of `Global.SUserId` and `Global.SPassword`. Did both the same?

Comment: yes i tried your solution, the value of Global.SUserId and Global.SPassword is also admin

Comment: and what is the actual value of username password in the SQL server?

Comment: Remove `Integrated Security=True`

Comment: username is sa and password is 123 in sql authentication

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
string ConString = "Server=DESKTOP-JTVC4I1\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=College;User Id=sa;Password=123;"
```

Also make sure your database name is correct. In description you said that your database name is "college" but in connection string you have used "College".